# Python SQLite3 injection

Tags: python, sqlite

I was wondering in my program for python I have purposely made it so I can use injection in my program. If I try to use this `enter a name: name; DROP TABLE test;` it does not work and enters it normally. If I am using `enter a name: name' DROP TABLE test;` it comes up with 
where it says enter a name it is obviously a variable.

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES('%s')" % test)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "DROP": syntax error
```

and if I use

```
enter name: test'"DROP TABLE test;"

c.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES('%s')" % test)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ""DROP TABLE test;"": syntax error
```

I only want to know how to so I can try it out in my programs only and to prevent against it(I know you should use ?)

Comment: Please read https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html to see how to pass arguments to SQL safely and prevent injections.

Comment: Did you read his question, Klaus? He **wants** this program to be injectable, he did it deliberately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VALUES clause needs a closing parenthesis, so you need to enter something like this:

```
name'); DROP TABLE test; --
```

(The `--` starts a comment, to prevent the final `')` in the original SQL statement from being interpreted.)

And Python's `sqlite3.Cursor.execute()` executes only a single statement, so this kind of injection does not work. Your program would need to use `executescript()` instead.
(But if you have a SELECT, you can use this to suppress any following filter conditions, such as `AND password='...'`.)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. now to guard against it in every way possible.